# Error: The current thread must be in Single Thread Apartment

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have this error whenever i try to open the Openfiledialog :

> The current thread must be in Single Thread Apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Make sure your Main function is marked as STAThreadAttribute. This exception is triggered only if a debugger is attached to the process.

My code :

```
    Dim ofg As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim lvp As New ListViewItem

    ofg.Multiselect = True
    ofg.Filter = "All Files|*.*"
    Statue.Text = "Loading..."

    If ofg.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        For Each File As String In ofg.SafeFileNames

            Dim hInst As IntPtr = Marshal.GetHINSTANCE([Assembly].GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0))
            Dim iIcon As Int32 = 0
            Dim hIcon As IntPtr

            hIcon = ExtractAssociatedIcon(hInst, File, iIcon)
            ico = Icon.FromHandle(hIcon)
            icondufile = ico.ToBitmap
            Img.Images.Add(icondufile)
            Dim C_File As New IO.FileInfo(File)

            Dim ItemFile As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(C_File.Name)
            lvp = Files_List.Items.Add(ItemFile)
            lvp.SubItems.Add(MD5Checksum(File))
            lvp.SubItems.Add(hash_generator("sha1", File))
            lvp.SubItems.Add(hash_generator("sha256", File))
            lvp.SubItems.Add(GetCRC32(File))
            lvp.SubItems.Add(hash_generator("sha384", File))
            lvp.SubItems.Add(hash_generator("sha512", File))
            lvp.SubItems.Add(C_File.FullName)
            lvp.SubItems.Add(C_File.Extension)
            lvp.StateImageIndex = lvp.Index

            ItemFile = Nothing

        Next

  Private Sub AddFilesToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddFilesToolStripMenuItem.Click
    trd = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf AddFiles)
    trd.IsBackground = True
    trd.Start()
    Timer_AddFiles.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems telling you what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Form Invoke method or set Thread Apartment as :

```
Dim ItemFile As ListViewItem
Private Function Init()  
 trd = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf AddFiles)
 trd.IsBackground = True
 trd.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.STA) ''You can set MTA or STA
 trd.Start(ItemFile)
End Function
Private Sub DoFormUiBased()
    '' Add your code here
End Sub
Private Function AddFiles(ByVal Argument As Object)
    Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf DoFormUiBased))
End Function
```

Comment: In multiThreading, dont forget to use ThreadSafe  or threadPool because Cross Thread may occur.